# Docker container - "Docker run" append bash command

Tags: bash, docker, containers

I´m executing following command:

```
sudo docker run IMAGE bash ~/commands.sh
```

where IMAGE is my docker image and commands.sh a script inside the container.

When starting the container with "docker run", I want to execute the script. But it doesn´t work. I get the following error-status:

```
Exited (127) Less than a second ago
```

This error-status means, it doesn´t know the command.
Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Does your image actually contain bash?  (Many Alpine-based images won't.)

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that your local bash (running on the host system) expands the `~` before it reaches the running docker container. Have you tried using an absolute path here?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all these different ways along with your attempts to debug the problem